# Firebase functions 'enforceAppCheck' : true, won't do anything

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I'm using firebase functions to build my system, I want to add extra layers of security to avoid brute force attacks and others and the app check mechanism looked like a nice solution

BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

i did everything writter in here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-enterprise-provider

my function looks like:

exports.test= functions.runWith({
timeoutSeconds: 30,
memory: '128MB',
enforceAppCheck: true
}).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
console.log(JSON.stringif(data));
console.log(JSON.stringif(context));
});

but yet it doesn't work

i can open postman or any other rest request maker put the function url and just post anything like

```
{
    "data" : { "foo" : {}, "bar" : "bar"}
}
```

no headers, just a post as this with the right url and the request goes through...

wasn't `enforceAppCheck: true` supposed to ban the random requests like this?
if i look the function logs i even get a log like this:

```
{
insertId: "6438df00000d1c3cc2e2d44e"
jsonPayload: {
message: "Callable request verification passed"
verifications: {
app: "MISSING"
auth: "MISSING"
}
}
labels: {3}
logName: "projects/qe/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-04-14T05:05:04.982509106Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "INFO"
timestamp: "2023-04-14T05:05:04.859196Z" 
}
```

***"Callable request verification passed"***

what verification? it was literally a random request

after this log line i get 2 more lines printing the stuff i put in the function
the context shows that context.app == null and context.auth == null

doesn't this app verification works for nothing? is firebase letting people randomly brute-force our functions?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to follow following steps to debug this issue:

To verify if Firebase `App Check` is working correctly, you can check if the `appCheckToken` property is present in the context object. If the `appCheckToken` property is present, it means that Firebase App Check has successfully validated the request. If the appCheckToken property is not present, it means that Firebase App Check has blocked the request.

You can verify the above using `console.logs` in your firebase function as follows:

```
export const op = functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 30, memory: "128MB", enforceAppCheck: true })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(context));
    // From Vs Code intellisense :
    // The App ID corresponding to the App the App Check token belonged to. 
    // This value is not actually one of the JWT token claims. 
    // It is added as a convenience, and is set as the value of the sub property.
    console.log(context.app?.token.app_id);
    console.log(context.app); // will print Appcheck data too
  });
```

Reference : [**https.CallableContext**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https.callablecontext#properties)

Comment: Have you checked that the request is coming from valid firebase App and it does also have App check token as per this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions). If you think my answer is incorrect, Also share the details so I can make it more useful for you.